# W10 on Virtual Machine doesn't seem to have bluetooth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bluetooth

First time using cloud VM, installed W10 but couldn't find or connect a device on bluetooth. After following some tuts on how to activate/add bluetooth I think there is no Bluetooth on this windows. Could it be a driver missing?

Comment: Ermmm....what bluetooth device inside Google's datacentres do you expect it to connect to, also why makes you think their VMs have access to a bluetooth adapter anyway?

Comment: As stupid the question might seems to you and other three that voted down. I need light here. If you or someone can give me great. Don't people play games on Cloud VM?

Comment: I had it connected via USB as well, shoudn't it work?

Comment: "Don't people play games on Cloud VM" - no, that would be an expensive and bad experience on a general purpose cloud system, unless it was designed to do just that, like Stadia, at which point that's ALL it can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when we are introducing by ourselves on a Cloud Platform, we don't know what kind of features or what are our possibilities we are able to use it, or if they are supported or included on it.

On this case, everytime that we are using Virtual Machine Instances at GCP, we only have access to some resources like number of CPUs, Network Cards, or kind of HDD/SSD or the size of them.

On this case, we are not able to use Bluetooth feature, because this is not a physical device that has it, I mean, is not available, even when the Windows System shows it.

For more reference about to use Windows instances at Google Cloud Platform, please review [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows).

I hope this information helps, and remember: There are no silly questions, only fools who do not ask. Have a nice day and stay safe.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Should I be able to connect it via USB at lease?

Comment: Remember that this is a Virtual Environment, this means that there are nothing physical. It is different like when you use for example a DELL server, you can use a mouse or keyboard, because it has physical ports where you can insert them. In this case is different, even you are using a VM that lives on Cloud, you are not able to use your physical ports located on your PC. So the answer is no, neither, you are not able to connect or use the USB ports.

Comment: Why do Keyboard and mouse work then? I thought would be the same.

Comment: Keyboard and mouse use a Virtual Feature that works on a Virtual Environment, this feature is not available for USB or Bluetooth.